# Can't resize NTFS partition

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-cloning, ddrescue

I'm cloning an old 1TB drive to a new 2TB drive. I've successfully managed to clone it, using `ddrescue` and [SystemRescueCD](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org), and can now boot into Windows on my new 2TB drive. However, the drive now has a 1TB partition and another TB of unallocated space. I'm trying to expand that partition to fill the drive.

First I tried Windows 10's partition manager, but the "expand volume" option is greyed out, since the volume is the C drive. Next, I tried booting onto my old 1TB drive and using the partition manager there, but I'm getting a blue screen that says "Your PC/Device needs to be repaired":

[image]

Nothing was wrong with this drive before, I just wanted to move to the bigger one. Not sure why this suddenly happened.

Anyway, third, I tried booting back into SystemRescueCD and using GParted, but it complains about bad sectors:

[image]

Its worth noting that the `ddrescue` command reported 8 kB of lost data in the clone, which may explain the bad sectors. But I'm not sure.

I've tried running `chkdsk /f` as suggested, but it made no difference.

So there's 3 questions here:

1. How can I resize my partition to make use of the terrabyte of unused space on the new drive?
2. Why is my brand new drive complaining of bad sectors? Did the bad sectors `ddrescue` encountered on the old drive somehow get copied to the new one? Or did I just get a bad drive from Amazon? Can the bad sectors be "repaired", or simply ignored somehow?
3. Is there a way I can save my old drive, in case I need to reclone it? I have no idea how it got into this state. I was under the impression that`ddrescue` was just reading from it.

Comment: You can re-size the partitions by downloading software tools such as "MiniTool Partition". Here is a link to download: https://downloads.tomsguide.com/MiniTool-Partition-Wizard-Bootable-CD,0301-51034.html

Comment: "option is greyed out, since the volume is the C drive". It shouldn't be an issue if a drive is C: I did shrink and expand C drives many times without any issues from Computer management->Disk management. The case probably that source drive has a disk issue. Try first cure it (MHDD, Victoria...) to be make sure there no bad sectors

Comment: @cybernard it's been running for over an hour and is stuck at 12%

Comment: Try on 2TB drive ``sfc /scannow`` to recover lost system file(s)

Comment: @ewok an hour?  For 2 TB you would be lucky to finish in 4 hours.

Comment: @cybernard fair enough. But it got up to 12% in like 10 minutes and has been hanging there since. Is that common? Also, the drive is 2TB but is it checking the whole drive or just the 1TB C volume?

Comment: @cybernard it completed, I went back into GParted and it resized without issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chkdsk /B c: is necessary to re-test the bad sectors so they can be cleared if they are working fine. After that Gparted should work just fine